# How can I display objects from different models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am doing website for game tournaments. I have models for matches,teams and players. I don't understand how to create view for the single match.

I tried to change queryset, but I don't know how to do it properly.
I did view for the sigle team, for the whole list of matches, but not for the single match.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from . import models
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404


class TestView(ListView):
    model = models.TestTeam
    template_name = 'home.html'

class TeamView(ListView):
    model = models.TestPlayer
    template_name = 'team.html'
# Single team players displaying
# There are displayed players who has team's slug in their kwargs
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        if 'slug' in self.kwargs:
            team_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            queryset = queryset.filter(team__slug=team_slug)
        return queryset


class MatchListView(ListView):
    model = models.TestMatch
    template_name = 'home.html'

class MatchDetail(DetailView):
    model = models.TestMatch
    template_name = 'match.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField


class TestTeam(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Team')
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TestPlayer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Player')
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Nickname')
    team = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, default='Team')
    # photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='', null=True)
    No = 'N'
    Yes = 'Y'
    STANDIN_CHOICES = [
        (Yes, 'Yes'),
        (No, 'No'),
    ]
    standin = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=STANDIN_CHOICES, default=No)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TestMatch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Match')
    leftTeam = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Left Team')
    rightTeam = models.ForeignKey(TestTeam, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+', default='Right Team')
# TODO complete slug of a match with slugs of the teams
    # it should be populated from leftTeam__slug and so on
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['leftTeam__name', 'rightTeam__name'])

    def __str__(self):
        return (str(self.leftTeam) +" - "+ str(self.rightTeam))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('match', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.TestView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('', views.MatchListView.as_view(), name='match'),
    path('matches/<slug:slug>/', views.MatchDetail.as_view(), name='matchDetail'),
    path('teams/<slug:slug>/', views.TeamView.as_view(), name='team'),
]
```

match.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

I want to have single match page. There must be shown 2 teams and their players. Explain me please, how can I do it.

Comment: You created the DetailView for the TestMatch object, so if a TestMatch exists, you should be able to see it at `localhost:8000/matches/<insert_the_matches_slug_here>/`. Are you encountering an error, or are you wondering how to get access to the `TestMatch` object within the template `match.html`? If it's an error, please post that error. If you aren't sure how to get to the match object, you can do that with the `{{ object.name }}` attribute in the template, thanks to the DetailView. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: everything you do is correct, what's the problem or what's the error?

Comment: I don't know how to display players in 'match.html' @RobertTownley

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't understand how to display players of the perticipating teams in 'match.html'

Comment: Then @RobertTownley already told you. `object` is the context variable that represents the specific `Match` you're viewing. And to get from the `Match` to the `Team` to the `Player`, read the [Django docs on how to access relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: @dirkgroten ok, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view, you can override `get_context_data()` method to set extra context data

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(MatchDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    left_team = TestTeam.objects.get(id=self.object.leftteam) # self.object is a TestMatch object
    right_team = TestTeam.objects.get(id=self.object.rightteam)

    left_player_list = TestPlayer.objects.filter(team=left_team)
    right_player_list = TestPlayer.objects.filter(team=right_team)

    context['left_team'] = left_team
    context['right_team'] = right_team
    context['left_player_list'] = left_player_list
    context['right_player_list'] = right_player_list

    return context
```

then in your template, you can use it as usual

```
Left Team = {{left_team.name}}
Left Player List:
{% for left_player in left_player_list %}
{{ left_player.name }} - {{ left_player.nick }}
{% endfor %}
```

you can read this [web](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) for more reference 
hope it can help you :)